# Memory leak in forceBridgeFromObjectiveC

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, memory-leaks, interface-builder

Memory leak using interface builder and auto generated code from Xcode.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Added 8 UIButtons to the UIViewControler in the storyboard.
2. Using IBOutlet collection connected all UIButtons to the Swfit source file.
3. Executed an app using Instruments -> Leaks
4. 80 Bytes memory leak was generated.

Responsible frame for this memory leak is: static Array._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC(NSArray, result : inout [A]?) -> ().

**How I could fix forceBridgeFromObjectiveC memory leak?**

Xcode: 7.2.1
iOS: 9.2.1

Comment: This looks like a leak in the Swift implementation, so the way to fix it seems to be: Just wait for the next version of Swift, or fix it in the actual Swift implementation and give Apple a pull request :)